# What is this design pattern known as in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was looking over the js source code for [Scrabb.ly](http://Scrabb.ly).

I've noticed that they would do something like so for each of their distinct "classes":

```
var Board = (function() {
  var self = {};

  // settings for board
  self.options = {
    debug: true,
    addedPlayTiles: function() {},
    clearedPlayTiles: function() {}
  };

  // set to true once the board has been setup
  self.isSetup = false;

  // quick access to square elements
  self.squares = {};
  self.squareCount = 0;

  self.setup = function(options) {
    self.log("Setting up board!");

    // set options
    _.each(options, function(val, key) {
      self.options[key] = val;
    });

    return self;
})();
```

Some code from the middle has been omitted but this should give you the general idea.

1. What is the purpose of the the following: `(function() { // code })();`  Is this the module pattern that I've seen talked about?  Is this meant to keep the global namespace clean?
2. What does this line mean?: `var self = {}`  Is the self object used to exposed 'public' members? How would you define a private function or variable?
3. How would you instantiate multiple "Boards" if you wanted to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called the Module Pattern.

The parentheses around the function mean it's being evaluated immediately after being defined -- so in essence it's a *Singleton*. Since it's an anonymous function, the definition is not stored - so you cannot readily create new instances of this object without a few modifications (which will be discussed later).

You are correct, `self`  contains the "public" methods and properties, as it were. Any variables that aren't defined in `self` are not visible to the outside because of the closure properties. However, any functions defined in `self` still have access to the private variables because in Javascript, functions maintain access to the context (including variables) in which they were defined -- with a few exceptions.. mainly `arguments` and `this`.

If you want to define multiple instances of this object, you would remove the parentheses (`var Board = function () { ... }`) and then use `var obj = Board()` to create an object. Note that it does not use the `new` operator.

Answer (score 4):

As [mentioned in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661725/what-is-this-design-pattern-known-as-in-javascript/3661731#3661731), that's the Module Pattern.

It is also known as the YUI Module Pattern or the Yahoo Module Pattern, mainly because it was made popular by this blog article:

- [YUI Blog: A JavaScript Module Pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) by Eric Miraglia

Regarding point 3, the Module Pattern is intended to be a singleton. However, the Module Pattern is easily transformed into a Constructor Pattern. You may want to check out the following presentation by [Douglas Crockford](http://l) for more information on this topic:

- [JavaScript: The Good Parts - Functional Inheritance](http://www.crockford.com/codecamp/The%20Good%20Parts%20ppt/5%20functional.ppt) [PPT] by Douglas Crockford

Answer (score 1):

`var self = {}` should have the effect of initializing self as an empty object literal; if self already existed, it should delete the old values and reinitialize as an empty array.

Comment: I think you mean "object" not "array"?